# Call web service in background and shows its data in both map view and table view

Tags: iphone, uitableview, mkmapview, uisplitviewcontroller

I am using Split view controller for iPad in which we need to show data from web service in table view and in Map view simultaneously.  Meaning we need to show same data in master view and detail view.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application 
   didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions

   self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen]
   bounds]];

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    MasterViewController *masterViewController = [[MasterViewController
    alloc] initWithNibName:@"MasterViewController" bundle:nil];

    UINavigationController *masterNavigationController = 
    [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:
    masterViewController];

    DetailViewController *detailViewController = 
    [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" 
    bundle:nil];

    UINavigationController *detailNavigationController = 
    [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:
    detailViewController];

    masterViewController.detailViewController = detailViewController;

    self.splitViewController = [[UISplitViewController alloc] init];
    self.splitViewController.delegate = detailViewController;

    self.splitViewController.viewControllers =
    @[masterNavigationController, detailNavigationController];

    self.window.rootViewController = self.splitViewController;

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

I just need to call web service and show data in both view.

So i will show pins in map from web service data and its detail in master view.

Then I need to store all data in database also.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like using the observer-notifier pattern will be good, using NSNotificationCenter. You can spawn an NSURLConnection, and in the delegate method when the download succeeds, just post an NSNotification. Then in any views that you want to update, just add an observer to this notification, and update the view as necessary.

If you haven't used notifications before, NSHipster's article on it has a good overview: http://nshipster.com/nsnotification-and-nsnotificationcenter/

Comment: i am new in iphone development ..Can u just explain me where i call web service in app delegate and how to use in both controllers..in deatil..with some code  or example..